# VueJs How to Split string from a variable in API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, split

I'm new in VueJs. I want to split a string with comma (,) and save it to another variable. This string is from API.
This is my API, i'm using json server

```
"featured-property": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Property 1",
        "address": "Address Property 1",
        "geo": "0.5307596, 101.4461512"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Property 2",
        "address": "Address Property 2",
        "geo": "0.5055971577036701, 101.452919"
    }
```

I want to split "geo" and save it into variable "lat" and "lng",so i can use it to vue2-google-maps. I'm using axios to fetch the API.

```
export default{
    name: 'PropertyDetail',
    data(){
        return{
            property: [],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setProperty(data){
            this.property = data
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        axios
        .get("http://localhost:3000/featured-property")
        .then((response) => this.setProperty(response.data))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    }
}
```

How to do it in vue ways..?
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data gives you the Array of Object from the JSON, then you can have a function like this when you loop through the array;

```
saveObject: function(object){
  var latLngArray = object.geo.split(', ');
  object["lat"] = latLngArray[0];
  object["lng"] = latLngArray[1];
}
```

and in your setProperty function, you can call it like this

```
setProperty(data){
   var arrayProperty = [];
   var self = this;
   data.forEach(function(item){
      arrayProperty.push(self.saveObject(item));
   })
   this.property = arrayProperty;
}
```

The `saveObject` function will manipulate the data you pass in. This is not the ideal way. it is better to just create a variable that is the same as the passed in object and just return that variable